# When to use perfect forwarding and when to be explicit?

Tags: c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding

Missing the ternary comparison operators in Python (e.g., `a <= b <= c`), I decided to create a utility for my project

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    bool between(T&& low, T&& test, T&& high)
    { return ( low <= test && test <= high ); }
```

I state at the outset that I clearly don't grok perfect forwarding, but I thought this was a tailor-made use for it.

This fails when mixing lvalues and rvalues:

```cpp
    int const low = 0;
    int const high = 10;

    int test = 42;

    between(low, test, high);
```

This gives a compile error:

```
    error: no matching function for call to ‘between(const int&, int&, const int&)’
    note: candidate: template<class T> bool between(T&&, T&&, T&&)
     between(T&& low, T&& test, T&& high)
     ^~~~~~~
    note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T’ (‘const int&’ and ‘int&’)
```

I thought the point of perfect forwarding was to be insensitive to constness in templates. Clearly, I was wrong, and this is *not* a candidate for perfect forwarding, but I would like to understand why.

(lest you get distracted trying to fix my compilation error, I changed the function signature to assume boolean operations are logically const:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    bool between(T const& low, T const& test, T const& high);
```

and the compilation errors go away. I could also pass by value and get the same effect)

Comment: "*I thought the point of perfect forwarding was to be insensitive to constness in templates.*" Ignoring the accuracy of this statement... your algorithm *is not* "insensitive to constness". Your `between` function does not modify its arguments. Nor is it reasonable for any `operator<=` overload to modify its arguments (unless it's not doing comparison testing). Therefore, there is no reason not to take the parameters as `const&`s.

Comment: If you want perfect forwarding (which it's not clear you do), you need three different types for the three parameters: `template <typename T, typename U, typename V> bool between(T&& low, U&& test, V&& high);` Otherwise, your declaration implies that the three arguments all have the same type.

Comment: In this very case, wouldn't be using `inline bool between(T low, T test, T high)` the better/simpler way?

Comment: @Neonit for int types, yes. But a template should be able to handle arbitrary (in this case) comparable types, some of which might not be cheap to copy. See Igor's comment. And also see the last sentence of my question where I point out pass by value works.

Comment: @jwm So you imply it has to be doubted that the compiler will definitely inline the function? Or would it make copies even when inlining it?

Comment: I'm not sure your point. I believe that a pass-by-value function must make copies. I make no assumptions about what the compiler will in-line or not; optimization is outside of my purview. Whether the compiler can safely decide to elide copies is a question for the language lawyers and optimzation experts.